# Ambiguous info message after git merge command

Tags: git, macos, vim, git-merge

Mac here. New to git here. Last week I cut a feature branch (named `feature/my-feature-1` off of `development` (mainline) and got all my changes working locally.

I now want to merge any changes that have been committed to `development` (since I cut my feature branch last week) locally (**including resolving any merge conflicts**) and then push my mergeable feature branch to the remote git server (GitHub) so that I can create a PR without merge conflicts.

So I commit all my final changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Final changes"
```

Then I switch to `development` and pull it:

```
git checkout development
git pull
```

Then I switch back to my feature branch and attempt to merge:

```
git checkout feature/my-feature-1
git merge development
```

And it appears that `vi` or `vim` opens in my terminal and I see the following message:

```
Merge branch 'development' into feature/my-feature-1

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

This makes no sense to me! I can't tell what's happened:

- Did it auto-merge `development` into my feature branch and it simply found no conflicts?
- Dit it auto-merge what it could, but found conflicts, and now its up to me to merge/resolve them manually? **(If so how do I query git to see what those conflicts are?)**
- Dit it not attempt to do any merging at all? **(If so why not?!)**

Comment: It's asking for a commit message for the merge commit.  You can edit the message, then save and quit the editor, and then the merge will complete.  (It wouldn't be asking for a commit message if it knew of any problems, such as merge conflicts, because it wouldn't be trying to commit.)

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdelsberger (+1) -- hmmm two quick followup questions for you if you don't mind!  **(1)** It sounds like `git merge development` is trying to auto commit?!? Is this a configurable behavior? Ideally I'd like to `git merge development` and once everything is good (either nothing to merge, or nothing that conflicts or I already manually resolved conflicts) I'd like to `git push` myself. Is this possible to do?

Comment: And **(2)** what would happen if it did detect merge conflicts?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-merge? Are you aware of what git merge does?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup this is just creating the commit. In this case it is a clean merge. If there were conflicts it would tell you so and you would need to fix the conflicts, then commit. In all cases you will still need to do a git push afterwards to push those changes upstream.

Comment: Thanks @ZzCalvinzZ (+1) but when you say "*this is just creating the commit; in this case it is a clean merge...*", where/how do I create/edit the message for this commit? Also do I **really** want this to be a commit?! I'm just pulling in work thats already been committed previously...

Comment: Use rebase and you will has more 'power' about what is happening and it will not generate a "merge" commit (that MANY times means NOTHING). 

I like use iterative mode( git rebase -i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Did it auto-merge development into my feature branch and it simply found no conflicts?

Yes it successfully did the merge and resolved all merge-able conflicts ( if there were any ). The fact that vi opened after the 'git merge' command is the proof that it did.

- Dit it auto-merge what it could, but found conflicts, and now its up to me to merge/resolve them manually? (If so how do I query git to see what those conflicts are?)

It did not find any conflicts. If it did and if it could not merge them itself, it would not open vi, but give a message something of the sort "Conflicts found. Please resolve all conflicts and commit". Its then that you'd have to worry about resolving conflicts and committing. Check this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/) to see how to resolve conflicts.

- Dit it not attempt to do any merging at all? (If so why not?!)

It did merge and the merge process is only waiting for you to save and exit before it finishes. As a tip on this particular vi screen, if you want to abort the merge, or not sure if you want to proceed with any changes further, delete all the lines ( :1,$d ), save and exit.

Comment: Thanks @Gautam (+1) - two quick followup questions which both concern your statement above "*It did merge and the merge process is only waiting for you to save and exit before it finishes.*" **(1)** By "*save and exit*" do you mean that I need to `:wq!` from `vi`? And **(2)** Is it safe to assume that any text content in that opened file will become part of the merge commit message? Thanks again!

Comment: (1) Yes, you need to do ":wq!" if you want to go ahead with the merge.
(2) Yes, except those beginning with '#'

Comment: Thank you (+1 again!). **Last** question (I promise!): once I save + exit with `:wq!` do I need to do a `git commit ...` or `git push` if I want to immediately push the changes to GitHub?

Comment: You do not need to do commit. You do need to do 'git push' though.

Answer (score 2):

So here is few things you need to know

**Merge**

Creates a merge commit, with automatic message

```
Merge branch 'XXX' into YYY
```

And you can change the message if you want. The commit history will look like below

[image: Git merge]

**Rebase**

Since you cut out the `feature` branch from the master branch, let's say you made a commit `F1`, `F2` to the feature branch and `D1`, `D2` commits were done on the development branch. Now if you don't want a merge commit, then you need to rebase your branch, so that it looks like it was cut from `D2` instead of the previous development head commit, doing rebase will change your commit to `F3`, `F4` and since you now have your base commit as `D2`, you can do a fast-forward merge.

[image: FF Merge]

If you use github and create pull request then you have few options

[image: Git merge option]

The first option `Create a merge commit` is what you are doing through command line. Basically it create a new merge commit

The other options `Squash and merge`, this will merge all your commits into a single commit and then add it to the branch your are merging it into. This will forward the base branch by just 1 commit

And the `Rebase and merge` would do what I already explained in `rebase`. This will forward the base branch by number of commits you had in your feature branch.

Hope this explains your queries, if not please feel free to comment and I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is normal info about mergin branches. The window you see is only a comment about merge two branches.

To finish merging simply do (seimcolon isn't optional):

```html
[esc]
:wq
```

You can change editor not to use vi/vim and choose nano or other editor. You can always use software for merging depending on IDE or OS you use.

It's good practice to use rebase instead of merge to get up to changes on develop branch (and then merge changes to develop from feature).